# Find substring position into string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, substring

I have the following strings

```
"www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-111/..."
"www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-222/..."
"www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-333/...".
```

I need to find the a-xxx in each one of them and use it as a different string.
Is there a way to do this?
I tried by using `indexOf()` but it only works with one character. Any other ideas?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is the reason you need to do this?

Comment: Did you try Google?  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: @navigator did you read that article? It's about retrieving part of a string, whereas the OP wants to find the index of one string within another. Also, w3fools etc...

Comment: He want to use it as a different string: "find the a-xxx in each one of them and use it as a different string"

Comment: `str.split('/')[3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RegExp

```js
var string = "www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-111/...";

var result = string.match(/(a-\d+)/);

console.log(result[0]);
```

or match all values

```js
var strings = "www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-111/..." +
  "www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-222/..." +
  "www.mywebsite.com/alex/bob/a-333/...";

var result = strings.match(/a-\d+/g)

console.log(result.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following RegEx in conjunction with JS's search() API

```
/(a)\-\w+/g
```

Reference for search(): http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg=/a-\d{3}/;
text.match(reg);
```

Comment: Please consider added more information / explanation about your answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer